# Neo4JRequest on spring-data-neo4j 4.1.0.M1

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Following reference documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.1.0.M1/reference/html/) there is the code to update a spatial index after node insert

```
final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

@Bean
ApplicationListener<AfterSaveEvent> afterSaveEventApplicationListener() {
return new ApplicationListener<AfterSaveEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AfterSaveEvent event) {
        Neo4jRequest<String> neo4jRequest = new DefaultRequest(httpClient);
        if(event.getEntity() instanceof Person) {
            Person person = (Person) event.getEntity();
            //Construct the JSON statements
            neo4jRequest.execute(endpoint,json);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

the problem si:
where is Neo4JRequest interface ?
it seems dissappeared from the package leaving no trace on the why and how.

does anybody have the same issue with index updating?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this section in the docs was not updated for 4.1 M1.
Here is how to do it in SDN 4.1 (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/332)

```
 @Bean
    ApplicationListener<AfterSaveEvent> afterSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<AfterSaveEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(AfterSaveEvent event) {

                if(event.getEntity() instanceof Person) {
                    Person person = (Person) event.getEntity();
                    String json = "construct the JSON";

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Components.driver().getConfiguration().getURI() + "/db/data/index/node/" + indexName);

                    try {
                        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
                       HttpRequest.execute(httpClient, httpPost, Components.driver().getConfiguration().getCredentials());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       //handle this
                    } 

                }
            }
        };
    }
```